# PHP: How to get this string value?

Tags: php, xml, class, arrays, object

I have an array with the following data:

```
[steamid] => stdClass Object
(
    [0] => Shakyor
)
```

How can I get the 'Shakyor' string from there?

- `$array->$steamid` doesn't work.
- `$array->$steamid[0]` doesn't work.
- `$array->$steamid->0` is not legal markup obviously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$array->$steamid->{0}
```